# slide divs automatically inside a container

Tags: html, css

I have a container that may contains multiple divs that I want to animate in order to be sliding automatically as shown in this example :

[image]

As you see in the picture, the divs are sliding right to left so that one would replace the other yet you can see them in the extremities of the container.

To reproduce this example, I created a simple example :

html :

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 4</div>

</div>
```

CSS :

```
#parent  {
    display: flex;
}
#parent > div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

Below the codepen project of the code I provided above :
https://codepen.io/zakigates-the-decoder/pen/XWXmGLN

Your help would be appreciated having the effect on the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use e.g [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/)? Here is my CodePen which fits to your example.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mreux/pen/GRopLYK)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how I wanted it.